# Bootstrap: HTML anchors not working from button/footer

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I am having trouble geetting anchor links (#) to function from within certain sections of my page, created based on a boostrap css theme.

It appears as though Plugins.js from Bootstrap breaks anchor links when accessed from within a button.

In the below example, the SEE MORE button will not do anything when clicked on (its colour changes to the disabled colour only) but works if right-click and open with is used.
The same anchor link, used elsewhere on the page, works as expected.

```
<div class="single_tab_content">
   <div class="head_title">
       <h4>TITLE</h4>
          <div class="separator2"></div>
   </div>
   <p>Some sample text</p>
    <a href="#portfolio" class="btn btn-primary">SEE MORE</a>
</div>
```

The plugins.js itself is too long to paste here but it's the standard, unedited one used in bootstrap themes.

Does anyone know a workaround to get this to work?

Comment: Looks like someone might have done a `$(".btn").on("click",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });` or similar

Comment: I was wrong. They did a `$("a").on("click",function() { return false; });`

Comment: @mplungjan I edited the question based on your first comment while you were replying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your main.js file you have this code [image]

Just add the class `.footer_widget` after the class `.navbar-collapse` then everything will work fine

```
 $('.navbar-collapse, .footer_widget').find('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 40)
                }, 1000);
                if ($('.navbar-toggle').css('display') != 'none') {
                    $(this).parents('.container').find(".navbar-toggle").trigger("click");
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. What a crappy plugin that breaks all links unless parent is specified in the selector

Comment: yea its really crappy i just checked everything i found out there is nothing wrong with the links until i found that that punch of code just specify only the `.navbar-collapse` links

Comment: That works perfectly for the footer. I added .single_tab_content after it and it also works just fine for the buttons now. A milion thanks!